# OrientDB - upload image via HTTP API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, orientdb, binary-data

Hey OrientDB Community.

I'm attempting to upload an image into my DB via HTTP API. In my super basic web-page, I select a file and click upload. Simple. Once the button is clicked, I have javascript handling it with jquery and ajax.

Context: This is an educational tool which will have student profiles with their pictures. These images won't be too big (10MB - 20MB-ish).

Here is the HTML upload form:

```
<h2 class="heading-blue">Upload Image</h2>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input id="upload_image" type="button" value="Upload" />
  </form>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
$('#upload_image').on('click',function(){
console.log("UPLOADING IMAGE");

var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

$.ajax
  ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:2480/uploadSingleFile/DemoPlayground",
    data: formData,
    ??
    ??
    success: function (){
      alert('SUCCESS!'); 
    }
});
});
```

I'm not sure what to use where it says "/uploadSingleFile/" in the ajax URL parameter. Also, I'm not sure what else needs to be included in the ajax call. (Hence the "??"'s up above).

Some possibilities that I've been reading about:

1. Call a server-side function and pass the binary data (the image) to the function for it to handle the rest. If this is a good idea, I'm not sure how to do it...so help would be appreciated.
2. I've read in a couple places that Orient uses Jetty to perform this action. Any pointers on that?

I've got other types of HTTP API to OrientDB requests working, but this one is troublesome and I can't figure it out on my own.

I'm open to looking at this from new angles. Please help! :) THANKS!

Comment: OH! I forgot to add this snippet from my ajax parameters:
headers: {
          "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)
        },
....just to make sure you know I'm not struggling at that part.

Comment: For anyone look at this, I haven't figured it out but I've gone a different route. I'm using Spring (https://spring.io/docs) and an OrientDB/Spring Data integration package on github (https://github.com/orientechnologies/spring-data-orientdb). I haven't used it very much yet so I can't report much but it seems promising